# Create a new Safe from another contract

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core, safe

I want to build a smart contract called Portal.sol that has a deployeNewSafe() function that does the following:

- deploys a new safe (from the contract)
- sets Portal.sol as the only owner of the new safe contract
- sets Portal.sol as a module of the new safe contract
- sets the allowances module as a module of the new safe contract

I've looked in the safe global docs and I can't seem to find any guide on how to deploy safes from a smart contract.

Could you kindly point me to any materials that might help me build this, including example implementations if there are any?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it to work:

1. Deploy a module, let's call it SafeGuard.sol
2. In that module, define an `initializeProxySafe()` function
3. `initializeProxySafe()` function calls `createProxyWithNonce` on the Gnosis Safe Proxy Factory contract (e.g. https://etherscan.io/address/0x76e2cfc1f5fa8f6a5b3fc4c8f4788f0116861f9b)
4. Then `initializeProxySafe()` calls `setup()` on the newly deployed Gnosis safe proxy instance. When you call `setup()`, make sure you make SafeGuard.sol (or whatever your module is) one of the owners of the Safe
5. abi encode `enableModule(address)` like

```
bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSignature("enableModule(address)", address(this));
```

6. Then `initializeProxySafe()` creates a signature - this is the tricky part. `execTransaction()` takes `signature` as a param, which is an `r,s,v` signature. The Safe proxy will do a bunch of checks on the signature which I had to trace through.

When you need to set the `v` value to `1`, the Safe waives through calls to `execTransaction()` *as long as an owner of the Safe is calling* `execTransaction()`.

Here's how I implemented the `createContractSignature()` function:

```
function createContractSignature()
      internal view
      returns (bytes memory)
  {

      // Safe signature checker waves through transactions with correct signatures sent by owners of the Safe
      // `r` is the address of a current owner of the Safe
      address addr = address(this);
      bytes32 r = bytes32(uint256(uint160(addr)));
      // `s` can be anything
      bytes32 s = bytes32(uint256(0x4100));
      // `v` set to 1 to indicate owner signature
      bytes1 v = bytes1(uint8(1));      

      // Manually concatenate the bytes together
      bytes memory signature = new bytes(65);
      for (uint i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
          signature[i] = r[i];
          signature[i+32] = s[i];
      }
      signature[64] = v;
      return signature;
  }
```

7. Now we SafeGuard calls `execTransaction()` on the Safe proxy passing `data` created in step 5 above (which enables the module) as well as the `contractSignature` and you're apples

```
    try gnosisSafeProxyInstance.execTransaction(
      address(gnosisSafeProxy), //to
      0, //value
      data, //data (`enableModule` signature encoded)
      Enum.Operation.Call, //operation
      0, //safeTxGas
      0, //baseGas
      0, //gasPrice
      address(0), //gasToken
      payable(address(0)), //refundReceiver
      contractSignature //contractSignature
    ) {
      //do something if needed
    } catch (bytes memory /*lowLevelData*/) {
      revert("Enable module call failed");
    }
```

And that's it! SafeGuard is now enabled as a module of the newly deployed proxy

Answer (score 3):

a simple example can be found in the [Safe Factories repository](https://github.com/5afe/safe-factories/blob/master/contracts/Safe_1_1_1_Factory.sol). The more tricky part will be to encode the setup data to set the correct modules. The easiest is to encode 2 `enableModule` transactions using [MultiSend](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0-libs.0/contracts/libraries/MultiSend.sol).

The encoding should be something along the lines of the following code (not tested so might require some adjustments:

```js
    function buildEnabledModule(address safe, address module) internal returns (bytes memory data) {
        return abi.encodePacked(
            uint8(0), // Call Operation -> 0
            address(safe), // To -> Safe where the module will be enabled
            uint256(0), // Value -> 0
            abi.encodeWithSignature("enableModule(address module)", module)
        );
    }

    function buildMultiSendEnable(address safe, address module1, address module2) internal returns (bytes memory data) {
        return abi.encodePacked(
            buildEnabledModule(safe, module1),
            buildEnabledModule(safe, module2)
        );
    }
```

This should be used as the `data` field in the [setup](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0-libs.0/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L75-L97) method and the `to` would be an instance of MultiSend/MultiSendCallOnly.

Comment: awesome thanks Richard I missed this answer I'll check it out. I got it to work by encoding a signature with v=1 – which bypasses most of the signature checks if caller is owner (in this case caller was the module I built) – and then calling execTransaction on the Safe with enableModule. I'll post the full answer soon. Thanks!